# Play a video from local itunes Library in a uiview frame

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, movieplayer

I have a **MPMediaItem** in which is a video of the local itunes library of the iPad.
how can I play in a UIView this now?
The following code does **not** work:

```
MPMediaItem *video = [allVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [video valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: videoView.bounds];  
[videoView addSubview: player.view];
[player play];
```

Comment: they are not all protected, but none works

Comment: and "url" is like "ipod-library://item/item.m4v?id=5362748905682455"

Comment: Apple suggest to use `AVPlayer`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Answer (score 0):

why does the following not work?

nothing happens...

```
MPMediaItem *song = [allVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]);
    NSURL *url = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:playerItem];
    player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    //[player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [player play];
```